# algorithm-- How to find nearest POI to 1 million coordinates in an efficient manner

Tags: java, algorithm, geocoding

This is post interview where I was required to implement this--

So I am given a list of restaurant POI's (about 2000 of them) in Euclidean coordinates

I am then given a list of user coordinates (1 million of them)

I was tasked with returning how many users are within a certain radius (10,15) of one single POI, and secondly, the radius required for 75% of users to be within distance of a POI

The distance is something I could calculate, but brute forcing it meant checking 1 million coordinates for 1000 coordinates, which took a very very long time.

What would be a more efficient way to do this instead?

Comment: Lots of ways of doing it, but basically you should be looking to partition the space into parts "worth searching", and parts "not worth searching".

Comment: You may want to search for 'spatial data structures', especially R-tree.

Comment: For first problem: Map Reduce could be another (resource hogging) way. For second problem: Cluster the points and then calculate the POI closest to the user. Then increase the radius to cover 75% of those user_poi distance.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use a framework that allows you to spatially index the coordinates and run efficient spatial operators. Mapinfo, Spatially aware database (Oracle Spatial - which might require additional licensing for production use), ESRI, open source, etc.

Typically action would be

1. load POI's in a spatially indexed container (Table with spatial index).
2. Load users in a spatially indexed container
3. extend POI's as a circular objects with required distance radius.
4. Spatially join/combine for users within POI circles

Those spatial join/combiners are available in different flavors of spatial operators.

If you just want to generate result as part of an exercise, and you cannot use any frameworks, I would suggest to take a few simple approaches.

1 M users is actually not super big - it is managable - problem is that these points are to be evaluated against 2000 POI. I believe the best way is to

1. generate bounding squares first around the POI using 2 x radius as the side.
2. This will allow you to fairly quickly evaluate which points are of interest to each POI. In principle only greater-than, less-than would be used as operators.
3. Having for each POI a set of users, you can further narrow it down by doing an actual distance calculation.

You can leverage all sorts of smart indexing and sorting to have this go much faster. The suggested R-Tree in a comment seems to be highly suitable if you have the time for implementing. This will help you in the second step above.

A much simpler approach - depending on how your coordinates are laid out (how your world looks like), is to divide up your world in bigger squares, and have first determined for each user and each POI to which square they belong. You can quickly determine all users within the same square of the POI, or any neighboring square as users of interest. Come up with a smart indexing/numbering scheme that can help you identify neighbors as well. Have list of users indexed to their squares through Hashmaps.

Comment: Sorry for the additional constraint, I wasn't allowed to use an outside framework that is already created

Answer (score 0):

Use a spatial lookup datastructure or database and make appropriate queries.

For the radius to enclose 75% of users you can always just binary search the radii using the known total user count and the outermost coordinates.